# Django permission inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, permissions

I'm trying to inherit from a class which has some permissions defined in it's Meta class, such as this:-

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_mymodel', 'Can view mymodel'),
        )
```

but when I create a model that inherits from it like this:-

```
class MySubModel(MyModel):
    pass
```

it doesn't inherit the permissions of the superclass.

Why is this and what is the best way to solve this problem without changing the MyModel class?

Comment: Is MyModel abstract? And does MySubModel define its own Meta class?

Comment: No, MyModel is not abstract. I've read that you can inherit permission from an abstract model but this one isn't. MySubModel does not define it's own Meta class.

Comment: The MySubModel model is in my app. The MyModel model is in a 3rd party app (hence me not being able to change it). The problem is, the MyModel app is using django guardian, and when the code in there tries to assign the view_mymodel permission to the MySubModel instance, it doesn't have that permission.